# error while trying to multithread excel macro using python

Tags: python, excel, vba, multithreading

We are trying to multithread our existing macro using a python script to split the job in different threads. We are passing file paths of two different excel files as arguments for our threads. However, we are getting an error that **"Coinitialization has not been called"**.

we got a probable solution on the internet for this error, where it is suggested to call CoInitialize
before dispatch(which I did as visible in the codes below). I used pythoncom.CoInitialize() in my code.
But it is not working(no reference to 'CoInitialize' in 'pythoncom.py' ).

Is there any alternative way to handle this Coinitialization error??

we are using python 3.8 and our excel files are macro-enabled.

`

```
  import os
  import win32com.client as win32
  from time import perf_counter
  import threading
  import pythoncom

  begin = perf_counter()
  print(f"start time - {begin}")
  run1_path = r"MacroToPython\POC\POC-Scripts\PMF1.xlxsm"
  run2_path = r"MacroToPython\POC\POC-Scripts\PMF2.xlxsm"


  def run_excel_macro(file_path, separator_character):
      pythoncom.CoInitialize()
      x1 = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
      x1.Application.visible = False

      try:
          wb = x1.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(file_path))
          x1.Application.run(file_path.split(sep=separator_character)[-1] + '!Run.run_file')
          wb.Save()
          wb.Close()

      except Exception as ex:
          template = "An Exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
          message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
          print(message)

      x1.Application.Quit()
      del x1


  separator_char = os.sep
  t1 = threading.Thread(target=run_excel_macro, args=[run1_path, separator_char])
  t2 = threading.Thread(target=run_excel_macro, args=[run2_path, separator_char])
  t1.start()
  t2.start()

  t1.join()
  t2.join()

  end= perf_counter()
  print("End time- {}".format(end))
  total_time_taken = round(end-begin,2)
  print("Total time(0)".format(total_time_taken))
```

`
**Error Message **

Exception in Thread 1:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File"..\Python\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py" line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch

IDispatch=python.connect(IDispatch)

pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221008,**'CoInitialize has not been called.'** None, None)

Answer (score 0):

CoInitialize should be called from the main thread only, and only once in the lifetime of an application.

Another good way to debug it would be to get the result of `pythoncom.CoInitilize()` are see what the values are to determine if an error has occurred.
Refer here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-coinitialize